# Using Task.Run(..) in a .NET property

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

## Summary

I have a normal class which has a normal property but that property has access to an async backing field.

**I'm not sure if this is the best/acceptable way to access the asyc method for this backing field.**

## Details

I've got a [C# library](https://github.com/PureKrome/HttpClient.Helpers) that helps testing the .NET `HttpClient` class.

This class has a property `public HttpContent HttpContent` which is access two private backing fields which some code uses later on.

One of these private backing fields is populated via an `async` method. This, being a property, isn't `async`.

When the value of this property is `set`, I extract the actual string content from it by calling the method `_httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` and also remember a reference to this instance via a class-global variable.

The actual code in question is this

```
private string _httpContentSerialized;

....

_httpContentSerialized = _httpContent == null
    ? "*"
    : Task.Run(_httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync).Result;
```

As such, **I'm not sure if the code I have (which seems to work, mind you) is the best way to do this** and I'm hoping someone can review this (as opposed to asking on SO for a 'how to do this' answer).

#### Extra Info to consider:

Being a *library* I have no idea how/where my library will be consumed/used:

- A console app?
- An ASP.NET app?

With this in mind, I'm not sure if the code I have written is acceptable and won't cause deadlocks for a .NET application.

Other suggestions have been to use `_httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

---

Here's some more of the code:

```
public class HttpMessageOption
{
    private HttpContent _httpContent;
    private string _httpContentSerialized;

    public HttpContent HttpContent
    {
        get { return _httpContent; }
        set
        {
            _httpContent = value;
            _httpContentSerialized = _httpContent == null
                ? "*"
                : Task.Run(_httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... you're gonna end up deadlocked. General rule of thumb, don't call the `Result` property of an awaitable. It's a bad time. Go read everything you can about async by Stephen Cleary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just literally lost the **async** part of your `ReadAsStringAsync` method. By calling the `Result` property of your `Task` object, you will block your **calling** thread since it is going to wait for the **async** thread to return with the result of the operation. The `Result` property is just like the `Wait` method.

You should use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait`, since:

1. `Result` and `Wait` will encapsulate your `Exception` into an `AggregateException`.
2. You could easily encounter a **deadlock situation**. You shouldn't block on **async** code normally.

However, without `Result` and `Wait` you simply **cannot** make a property safely **async**. It is not supported in **C#**, only methods, lambda expressions or anonymous methods can use `await`. Properties should perform fast and non-blocking operations. If you want to perform a long running activity, **don't** make it a property (or just call a synchronous method in the setter).

```
private HttpContent Content;
private string SerializedContent;

public async Task SetHttpContent(HttpContent Content)
{
    this.Content = Content;
    SerializedContent = await Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

// ...

await SetHttpContent(new object);
```

Comment: Sweet - I really like what this suggests: when you `SET` .. it's more than just some backfield that is occuring .. but _other_ magical stuff occurs underneath ... so be warned/here-be-dragons/etc.  Now I have another, new problem: ... some point _later on_ ... i'll need to block/wait when I do this SET because the calling code is sync, not async .. but that's another problem for another hour :(

Answer (score 4):

I find it is not obvious to the user what happens when he sets the `HttpContent` and that he needs to actually wait while setting it.

I prefer to have a method like

```
public async Task<string> GetSerializedHttpContent()
{
    return _httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

reather a property that does more then I might actually need. What if I never use the `_httpContentSerialized` but need the `HttpContent` for other purposes? You might say that you use it but hay, the example contains only a single property so we can only guess about its real usage and the backing field. Nevertheless, it should not do any work but setting a field.